# Adding 2 HDDs as mirroning on existing OS (centos)

Tags: centos, hard-disk, raid

I have a NAS with 2 x 1TB HDDs and I added two new HDD-s:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1        2550    20482843+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2            2551        2681     1052257+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3            2682        2812     1052257+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb4            2813      121601   954172642+   5  Extended
/dev/sdb5            2813      121601   954172611   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.3 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.3 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Disk /dev/sdd doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md0: 20.9 GB, 20974338048 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 5120688 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md2: 977.0 GB, 977072685056 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 238543136 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 1077 MB, 1077411840 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 263040 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@backup ~]#

[root@backup ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      1052160 blocks [2/2] [UU]
md2 : active raid1 sdb5[1] sda5[0]
      954172544 blocks [2/2] [UU]
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      20482752 blocks [2/2] [UU]
unused devices: <none>
[root@backup ~]# –
```

How can I add those 2 x 2TB HDDs on existing RAID and create /home2 partition?

Comment: You don't add disks to an existing raid, you make a new one. `mdadm` is the command you need.

Comment: Hello Henrick, I am totally clueless, do you have step by step instructions? Thanks

Comment: It's been a long time since I had to do this manually,but something like `mdadm --create /dev/md3 --level 1 --raid-devices /dev/sd[cd]` - But don't come crying if that trashes your system.

Comment: @Henrik that's not quite right, it uses the raw disks instead of a partition

Comment: @IonuţCălugăru What happened to sda? Also, can we get the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`?

Comment: @derobert: And what's wrong with that? I know a lot of tools like to partition discs before making a md device, but technically it just a waste of space if you going to use the whole disc anyway.

Comment: @Henrik well, it's not how his other arrays are set up. So it's probably not how OP's NAS expects the disks. Also, losing a few MB to make sure the disks show as in use (because otherwise they'll not have valid partition tables), aren't destroyed if a bootloader is installed on them, etc... seems like a good trade-off to me. (And if you're really worried about the space, you can keep loss to 32KiB—trivial on a multi-TiB drive).

Comment: If the OP is doing this manually, I would guess this isn't some "fancy" NAS box that cares. But I agree that it's not much space (that's why I said "technically"). I don't remember (and have to go offline in a few minutes, so I don't have time to read documentation) a simple command to partition the discs, so someone else will have to step up for that.

Comment: @derobert [root@backup ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      1052160 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb5[1] sda5[0]
      954172544 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      20482752 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
[root@backup ~]#

Comment: @IonuţCălugăru Please [edit] your question to add the information requested in comments—for one thing, that lets you keep the formatting! Anyway, I've gone ahead and done so for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing RAID arrays (all three of them) are mirrors (RAID1). You can add more disks to them, but that just adds more copies—so you need to create additional arrays. (You hopefully already know this, but your question was to add to the existing RAID.)

If your NAS has some interface to use (e.g., a web interface) you may want to use that. If you manage it via the CLI with standard Linux tools:

1. Note that I'm not actually trying this on a VM while answering—it's from plenty of experience using Linux RAID. It's possible I've made a typo, if you get an error—it might be my mistake.
2. I'm not sure what your three arrays are used for. `md2` is surely your data; it's by far the largest. `md0` and `md1` might be rootfs and boot, respectively, guessing by their sizes. If that's what they are, it's possible you actually want to create partitions on these new drives for those arrays (they need to be the same size or larger than the partitions `sda1`/`sb1` and `sda2`/`sdb2`).
3. Use `cfdisk`/`fdisk`/`gdisk`/`sfdisk` etc. to create a partition table on each of the new drives. You may want the two partitions mentioned above, and one partition with all the (remaining) space. I'll call the big one `sdcX` (as it might actually be 1, 3, or 5). Similarly, on the other disk `sddX`.
4. If you added partitions for the other two arrays, you add them like this:

   ```
   mdadm -G /dev/md0 -n 4        # change number of devices to 4
   mdadm -a /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1   # add sdc1
   mdadm -a /dev/md0 /dev/sdd1   # add sdd1
   ```

   and repeat for `md1` (using `sdc2` and `sdd2`)
5. Create a new array for the big part of the new disk:

   ```
   mdadm --create --level 1 -n 2 --bitmap internal /dev/md3 /dev/sdcX /dev/sddX
   ```

   Your existing arrays, for some reason, do not have bitmaps. Bitmaps allow *much* quicker recovery in the event of a power failure (copying only recently-changed data, instead of remirroring everything). If your mdadm refuses to accept the `--bitmap` argument (or you've decided you don't want bitmaps), leave out `--bitmap internal`.
6. Create a filesystem on the new array. This assumes ext4; you can of course use whichever filesystem you desire. Note that there is no need to wait for the sync to finish, you can do this immediately after the `mdadm --create`.

   mkfs.ext4 -L HOME2 /dev/md3    # -L sets the label
7. `mkdir /home2` and add the new filesystem to `/etc/fstab`. Then go ahead and `mount /home2`.

That should be it. You can see the sync status in `/proc/mdstat`, e.g., `watch -n60 --diff 'cat /proc/mdstat'` to watch it. You can go ahead and start copying data to the new array immediately, but note it may not be fully protected until the sync is done.